# 3 switches, one lamp with existing wiring

Tags: wiring, high-voltage, lamp, toggle-switch

I have an existing wiring with two switches for 1 lamp.

[image: Existing wiring]

How to add third independent switch without changing to much wiring inside walls (usual wiring [with the triple switch in the middle of circuit between two two ways switches] is not fit, since it will require replacing three wires inside concrete walls)

Thank you

Comment: Thank you  The circuit is correct. It has two independent switches. So each switch either connect live to lamp or shortcut llve to live (and switches lamp off). The circuit you proposed is what I know also, but this one will require replacing wires inside wall and I want to avoid it. So I am looking for adding another switch into existing circuit

Comment: I misread it as two contacts on the same switch. I'll delete the comment but here's the link again. See http://lightwiring.co.uk/tag/intermediate-light-switch-wiring. Thanks.

Comment: I got it, but I am looking to add another switch without too much rewiring

Comment: I did not payed attention on comments inside the post. Adding intermediate switch indeed should solve the problem